# Creating a multimap in redis

Tags: redis

With redis, I need to create a multimap (In a C++-esque type a: `Map<String, Set<String>>` -- but since redis doesn't support nested data-structures, I will have to hack something.

One obvious way of this is going to to use a plain redis set, but dynamically create the key. So if I was storing:

`K1 -> V1, V2, V3`

`K2 -> V4`

`K3 -> V5,V6`

which would mean I'd be creating 3 different sets (`mm:k1`, `mm:k2` and `mm:k3`) ... and probably a 4th set, to keep track of the keys for account keeping purposes.

Is this going to backfire on me, (in performance terms) or is there a better way of creating a multimap?

Answer (score 0):

Redis provides Hash Data structure, Which is a key value pair, You can smartly use this to store multiple values against a single key. 
like:

```
key - {v1, v2, v3}
```

Serialize your set of strings as a single value and store it against a redis hash.

Usign redis hash you can get all values against a key, and set all values at one go. 
But you can not get/update/insert a particular value in your set stored against a key

Comment: There's a problem with serializing values: you can't then incrementally update such set. Only rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, that's true, as Hash does not support nested data structure, so one need to store these as a single value.